# Why updating brightness filter has not effect in Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I'm updating DOM element's brightness/contrast from JavaScript:

```
let style = `brightness(${brightness}%) contrast(${contrast}%)`;
element.style.filter = style;
```

This happens when the user holds left mouse button and moves cursor. However, the brightness/contrast does NOT change in Safari (on Mac) unless the scroll bars are visible. However, the brightness does change in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge). Is it a bug in Safari? How do I make it work in Safari?

Demo: https://l36vng.csb.app/

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-vaughan-l36vng?file=/main.js:2207-2306

PS. This also does not work in Safari on iOS (if I include touch event handlers to the code above). My Mac Safari version is 16.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the latest Technology Preview (Release 160 (Safari 16.4, WebKit 18615.1.14.3)).

For the time being, you can workaround the issue by adding a super fast transition on the filter property, this will make current stable happy and update the filter as expected.

```js
// Change brightness/contrast of the image by holding
// left mouse button on the image and moving cursor.
// Moving horizontally changes brightness,
// moving vertically changes contrast.
class Brightness {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;

    // x and y mouse coordinates of the cursor
    // when the brightness change was started
    this.startPosition = null;

    this.brightnessPercent = 100;

    // Current brightness/contrast percentage.
    this.currentAmount = {
      brightness: 100,
      contrast: 100
    };

    // True if the user holds left mouse bottom, which
    // indicates that brightness is being changed.
    // False by default or when the left mouse button is released.
    this.active = false;

    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    let element = this.element;

    // Start changing brightness
    // -----------------

    element.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      if (e.button !== 0) return; // Not a left mouse button
      this.active = true;
      e.preventDefault();
      this.startChange(e);
    });

    // End changing brightness
    // -----------------

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      this.active = false;
    });

    // Drag the pointer over the bar
    // -----------------

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (!this.active) return;
      this.change(e);
    });
  }

  startChange(e) {
    this.startPosition = this.positionFromCursor(e);
  }

  change(e) {
    let position = this.positionFromCursor(e);

    let xChange = position.x - this.startPosition.x;
    this.changeCurrentAmount(xChange, "brightness");

    let yChange = position.y - this.startPosition.y;
    this.changeCurrentAmount(yChange, "contrast");

    this.changeImageStyle();
  }

  changeCurrentAmount(change, type) {
    change /= 2; // Decrease rate of change
    change = Math.round(change);
    let amount = 100 + change;
    if (type === "contrast") amount = 100 - change;
    if (amount < 0) amount = 0;
    this.currentAmount[type] = amount;
  }

  changeImageStyle() {
    let brightness = this.currentAmount.brightness;
    let contrast = this.currentAmount.contrast;
    let css = `brightness(${brightness}%) contrast(${contrast}%)`;
    this.element.style.filter = css;
  }

  positionFromCursor(e) {
    let pointerX = e.pageX;
    let pointerY = e.pageY;

    if (e.touches && e.touches.length > 0) {
      pointerX = e.touches[0].pageX;
      pointerY = e.touches[0].pageY;
    }

    return { x: pointerX, y: pointerY };
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const imageElement = document.querySelector(".Image");
  new Brightness(imageElement);
});
```

```css
.Image {
  /* Safari bug workaround */
  transition: filter 1e-6s linear;
}
```

```html
<img
    class="Image"
    width="512"
    height="512"
    src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/df185589006321d70d37d1a59040d7c3/df57f19b4b4b783a-cb/s250x400/e76347d6b1cb4aa08839036fb0407a9f6108a0ab.jpg"
  />
```

Comment: Yep, transition works. Thanks! Out of curiosity, how did you find it out? Seems a pretty random workaround to me :D.

Comment: @Evgenii I fiddled around in the dev tools enabling and disabling the property, saw that it did trigger the update and thought of that workaround to force this update. That's actually a quite recurrent pattern that some rendering aren't done when they should in various browsers, and forcing filter/opacity changes are the usual workarounds.

Comment: This workaround didn’t quite work for me, maybe because `1e-6s` is too short. I changed it to `0.01s` and it seems to work now.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie oh that's weird. Which version do you have? The current stable 16.3 (18614.4.6.1.5) seems to have the fix shipped in, but at the time I wrote that answer 1e-6s was working fine. Did you by chance try values in between, and 0.01 is really the smallest you found? Also, if you're using the latest version of Safari and still need this workaround, could you provide your case in a link? Maybe that's yet a different triggerrer that they didn't fix?

Comment: Looks like I have a somewhat old version of Safari (Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12)). I did not try other values, just `1e-6s` that worked sometimes but not always and then `0.01s` that seemed to work reliably and still felt short enough (it's shorter than one frame).